# Android : Paypal Preapproval API operation (Example needed)

Tags: android, paypal-subscriptions

Is there any working example for PayPal preapproval API operation. I went through some tutorials,. But they are specifying some preapproval key for the transaction. How will we get this key?

Answer (score 2):

if you talk about [Preapproval API Operation](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPreapproval) then the preapproval key is something the OTHER party returns to uniquely identify the transaction - for example, in their `Order` table they might have `uniqueidentifier PayPalPreapprovalKey = newguid()` field specifically for this purpose (if `Order` is the entity of the transactions).

does it make sense?